# AWS Lambda timesout with boto3.resource('s3')

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, timeout, boto3

I have created a lambda to react when files are uploaded to a bucket.
One of my first actions is to retrieve the version_id of the file using boto3.
Below is a function which get the version_id based on bucket and key.
The `s3_resource.Object` call seems to work fine. But if I un-comment the line which prints the actual version_id, then my lambda times out (timeout is set to 120s).

The print of the object itself seems to work fine, it's only if I try to print the version_id that it times out. Would this have something do the with the NAT gateway?

```
def get_file_version_id(bucket, key):
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
    file_obj = s3_resource.Object(bucket,key)
    print(f'file_obj: {file_obj}')
    #print(f'version_id: {file_obj.version_id}')
    #return file_obj.version_id
    return "Some Return Value"
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the high-level [Resource](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/resources.html) API calls rather than the low-level [Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html) API calls.

Resources, such as `s3.Bucket`  have attributes and these are lazy-loaded properties. So, when you create an `s3.Object`, that's a purely local thing. But when you try to access one of its properties, e.g. the content of an existing object or its version ID, the boto3 SDK will then make an actual API call to the S3 service.

The reason that your code times out is most likely that you do not have a network path to the S3 service. That probably means that you are running your Lambda function in a VPC and you have either deployed it in a public subnet or in a private subnet without also giving that subnet a default route to the internet via a NAT and Internet Gateway or an S3 VPC Endpoint.

So, either deploy your Lambda function outside of VPC. Or, if you need it to be in a VPC, then deploy it into a private subnet of your VPC (not a public subnet) and then ensure you have IGW and NAT in your public subnet and a default route from the Lambda's private subnet to the NAT. Or alternatively go the private subnet and S3 VPC Endpoint route.

PS check the `event` parameter passed into your Lambda function handler, just in case it actually provides you with the version ID. I'm not sure if it does or not, but it would be good to check.

Comment: Another option is [S3 VPC Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-vpc-endpoint-for-amazon-s3/).

Comment: @kichik yes, I mentioned that option twice. It's a good option, if appropriate.

Comment: Oops, missed it. Sorry!